# SQL Server database roles

Tags: sql-server-2008

As I understand it, Users assigned to the db_datareader role have the rights to read all tables in the database and those assigned to db_datawriter can update all tables.

Is there a database role that gives a user rights to execute all stored procedures?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to roll your own.

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor;
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'username';
```

Comment: Not since SQL Server 2005 if you use permission on the schema

Comment: @Joe: After I create the db-executor role, i will then have to grant that role permission to execute all stored procedures and every time I create a new SP, I'll have to modify the role to add exec rights to the new proc, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT EXEC ON SCHEMA::dbo
```

You can substitue dbo for your particular setup